# Warn About Update On UnmountedReact Component

Tags: reactjs

The day I develop my own react blog, I got a problem, need your help, and my english is so poor, please excuse typing errors.

I write code with React 16.x, and the react dispatch a warning:

> **Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
>   Please check the code for the Post component.**

[image]

The Post Component call a getCategories() function with a async request in ComponentDidMount lifecycle method, and then I click a link to another Component after the Post Component has been rendered, it dispatch the warning.

I have Try to add a tag:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._isMounted = true;

  this.getCategories()
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._isMounted = false;
}
```

then in my getCategories:

```
fetch({
    ...API.getCategories,
    data: {
      include: post.categories.join(',')
    }
  }).then(res => {
    if (res && res.data && this._isMounted) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        meta: Object.assign({}, prevState.meta, {
          categories: res.data
        })
      }));
    }
  });
```

still have the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the state after a component mount will trigger a second `render()` call and can lead to property/layout thrashing. You are getting this warning because you are setting the state in `componentDidMount()`

Please read [this](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md) for more details.

Comment: Thanks，i read it, but I actually need to request some data in this component， and it just used in this component.

Comment: Yes，but I don‘t want to put all states into the redux,  following the 
Best Practices of redux.

Comment: Try this `componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(api.url+"dishes").
      then((dish) => {
        this.setState({ dataSource: dish })
        console.log(dish);
      }).
      catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }`

Comment: [https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, the problem is that the user link to other component before the request resolved. I have try to add a ref wrapEl to a DOM and in the request success callback, add a `if` condition, only if the this.wrapEl exists, the setState will execute, this can be ok.